# Computational complexity for a specific data

Tags: performance-testing, performance-estimation

If complexity is `O(nlog2(n))`...
How to prove execution time for data like `10e7`if we know that for data like `10e5`execution time is 0.1s?

Comment: You don't. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: it has nothing common with complexity-theory. It is simple mathematical problem and the `computational complexity` here is just a buzzword. Make a proprtion and you'll get the desired answer

Comment: You cannot know the running time of algorithm without running it.

Comment: Perhaps you should be considering tags more like: [performance-estimation] and [performance-testing]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: To my knowledge, you don't prove it in this way.

More verbosely:
The thing about complexity is that they are reported in [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), in which any constants and lower order terms are discarded.  For example; the complexity in the question `O(nlog2(n))`, however this could be the simplified form of `k1 * n * log(k2 * log(k3 * n + c3) + c2) + c1`.

These constants cover things like initialization tasks which take the same time regardless of the number of samples, the proportional time it takes to do the `log2(n)` bit (each one of those could potentially take 10^6 times longer than the `n` bit), and so on.

In addition to the constants you also have variable factors, such as the hardware on which the algorithm is executed, any additional load on the system, etc.

In order use this as the basis for an estimate of execution time you would need to have enough samples of execution times with respect to problem sizes to estimate the both the constants and variable factors.

For practical purposes one could gather multiple samples of execution times for a sufficiently sizable set of problem sizes, then fit the data with a suitable function based on your complexity formula.

In terms of proving an execution time... not really doable, the best you can hope for is a best fit model and a significant p-value.

Of course, if all you want is a rough guess you could always try assuming that all the constants and variables are 1 or 0 as appropriate and plug in the numbers you have: `(0.1s / (10^5 * log2(10^5))) * (10^7 * log2(10^7)) = 11 ish`

Comment: What is ish in your equation? Isn't the result 14?

Comment: I ran the following through Octave `complexity = @(x) x * log(log(x)); 0.1 / complexity(10^5) * complexity(10^7)` and got 11.377.  I report it as 11ish because to assert more accuracy than two significant figures would be pushing it given the number of assumptions that were made to calculate it.

Comment: On second glance, I reinterpreted `log2(x)` to be 'base-2 logarithm of x' rather than `log(log(x))`, giving the following octave code: `complexity = @(x) x * (log(x)/log(2)); 0.1 / complexity(10^5) * complexity(10^7)` and a result of 14.

Comment: @kappaj Yes, LaTeX would be helpful. Take a look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow) for workarounds.  If you found it on an exam question, I would suggest asking your tutor/lecturer about it; to me it seems like a trick question to see if students know the difference between computational complexity and execution time.